# Kendo UI Grid ASP.NET MVC Wrapper ParameterMap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is there a way to define the parameterMap option for a Kendo UI Grid via the server side ASP.NET MVC wrappers?

I need to change local time into UTC time before sending up a filter command to the server, and this appears to be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of...

You can specify a string as the `parameterMap` setting, and this string can either be a JavaScript function directly, or the name of a JavaScript function that is found on the page.

`.parameterMap("myParamMapFunction");`

or

`.parameterMap("function(data){ /* do stuff with the data */}");`

Comment: So I need to do this via JavaScript? There is no way to do this via the mvc wrapper?

Comment: @Derick Bailey  How can I use this as a MVC wrapper in Kendo Scheduler?